# AWS QuickSight Fetch Dahshboard from Shared folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-quicksight

I need to fetch dashboards resides in a shared folder using rest api. On documentation I am not able to find any APIs to do operations with shared folders. Let me know if someone have tried the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has recently updated to allow working with folders including looking at what objects are in the folders see - [The API Reference here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_ListFolderMembers.html)